# Выпадающее меню сайта на html и CSS

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток! Господа, помогите сделать адекватное выпадающее меню для сайта.
Что мы имеем:
Решил потренироваться, и для этого выбрал вот [этот](http://w3layouts.com/jolly-games-a-games-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/) шаблон.
Код меню шаблона на html + CSS + JavaScript:

```js
    <!--script-for-menu-->
    <script>
    $( "span.menu" ).click(function() {
      $( ".top-menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
   </script>
   <!--script-for-menu-->
```

```css
.top-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left:0%;
  top: 78%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.top-menu ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 color: #fff;
 float: left;
 vertical-align: top;
}
nav a {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 font-size: 1em;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
 outline: none;
}
.top-menu ul li a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1.2em 4.38em 1em 4.3em;
  font-weight:400;
}
.top-menu ul li a.color1{
   background: #5bb2fc;
}
.top-menu ul li a.color2{
   background:#ffa659;
}
.top-menu ul li a.color3{
   background: #B881CF;
}
.top-menu ul li a.color4{
 background: #fec63f;
}
.top-menu ul li a.color5{
 background:#58ebd3;
}
.top-menu ul li a.color6{
 background:#ff7a85;
}
.top-menu ul li a:hover{
   opacity:0.8;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
 span.menu{
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   background: url(../images/nav.png)no-repeat 0px 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   right: 3%;
   top: 24%;
 }
 .top-menu{
  width:100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(35, 103, 160, 0.56);
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index:9999;
 }
 .span_2 {
   margin-top: 2em;
 }
 .top-menu ul{
  float:none;
  width:100%;
 }
 .top-menu ul li{
  display:block;
  float: none;
 }
}
```

```html
    <span class="menu"></span>
    <div class="top-menu">
     <ul>
     <li class="active"><a class="color1" href="index.html"  >Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="color2" href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="color3" href="typography.html">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="color4">Blog</a></li>
         <li><a class="color5" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a class="color6" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Если, кому-нибудь не трудно, помогите разобраться, а то я сам [делал](https://www.mobila.name/post/5172c6cbb4ab3/) по образцу с сайта, но у меня получилось, что меню сложилось в один угол. После этого  попробовал еще сам. Опять ерунда. Круто было бы увидеть выпадающее меню по наведению. 
Заранее спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 3):

```css
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    }

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    background: #efefef;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

    nav ul:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }

        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }

            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #757575;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    nav ul ul {
        background: #5f6975;
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
    }

        nav ul ul li {
            float: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
            position: relative;
        }

            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 15px 40px;
                color: #fff;
            }

                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #4b545f;
                }
nav ul ul ul {
 position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

результат:

[image]

информация отсюда:
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu